# iOS Facebook Integration

Tags: iphone, facebook, ios

I am working on simple facebook integration that allows users to post high scores to their wall. The way doodlejump handles this is my inspiration. I have it functioning, but it's not very clean and I'm not sure what to do.

I followed the instructions at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile to get up and running. One of the first things it has you do it call `[facebook authorize:nil delegate:self]`. After that you can call `[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self]` to make a post to the users wall. I have two issues with this.

First, when you call authorize it exits your app as that is facebook's new desired methodology as part of "One Single Sign-On" (OSS). That ok, what isn't ok is that my app is doing this even if the user is already signed on. I do not see a way to check if the user is already signed on.

The second issue is that it exits my app to authorize my app to post something to facebook. It seems acceptable to exit the app to sign on to facebook. Most users will have already done this, so no big deal. But my app should not have to exit just to get user authorization to post something. DoodleJump doesn't do that but I'm not sure how.

I tried digging through old posts but the SDK has changed so a lot of them are no longer valid. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the latest Facebook SDK (located at [Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)) and it's example I have determined that this is the expected behavior.

It is built around the new fangled "fast app switching" so it looks like that is just what happens.

A little lame imo but if that's what Facebook engineers have determined to be the optimal process then so be it.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Turned out it was because I hadn't set the URL Schemas in info.plist Where it says to fut fbYOUR_APP_ID make sure that you do this how they say. Your plist file should say something like fb12345  and then it will identify that the user has logged in correctly. offline_access will then work as a result

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the answer you are looking for, but the app 'Hipstamatic' connects with facebook for photo upload (which I assume/hope is a similar process as wall posting) from within itself.

It could be worth seeing if they would be able to guide you if you sent the devs an e-mail?

I think they solve this issue by calling an iframe of sorts within the app, connecting the app to facebook and performing facebook activities, then closing once complete.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **[ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/)**
It's an open source library for iOS to share links, images and more. It's very simple and also works with Twitter and other social networks.

The site also contains some video tutorial and some code examples to integrate the Facebook API, Check [this](http://www.getsharekit.com/tutorial/facebook)

Answer (score 0):

What permissions are you requesting? If you don't ask for `offline_access` the framework will make the user log in each time.

Comment: I was initially requesting no extra permissions, but adding offline_access did not change the behavior.