# Facebook Integration in iOS app

Tags: iphone, facebook

I need to post a user-specific text, determined by him, on his wall/timeline when he presses a button (in facebook's tutorial, they make the user login when the app launches, and then it does nothing).
There is a lot of information on the internet but every site does it in other way.
Just wanted to know if there's a specific way to do it.
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4991018/ios-facebook-integration

Comment: this is a duplicate one, go through following post-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209205/facebook-integration-in-iphone-os-4-0-or-later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick easy way to add facebook to your app is ShareKit (http://www.getsharekit.com/). This also allows you to add other social network site to your app.

Comment: Can I use it only for facebook? Because I already integrated twitter (thank god for the twitter framework!)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try Socialize: http://www.GetSocialize.com.  It'll allow app users to comment & like within the app, with the option of also sharing out to a social network (Facebook currently live; Twitter coming).  Full feature list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features

DROdio